# Documentation of STM32F3 for Ethernet/TCP-IP

Tags: stm32, ethernet

I want to use Ethernet TCP-IP communication between an STM32F3 and a computer.
I am using an ENC28J60 module for this. But all the codes I've tried do not work. Where can I find documentation for this communication?

Resources I've used:

https://github.com/xukai871105/uip_freemodbus_tcp (I changed it to STM32F3 but the communication didn't succeed).

https://github.com/search?q=enc28j60+tcp+stm32

Comment: As is, the question is probably too broad to be answered, unless you really are asking "how can I find documentation", because in that case the answer will be "web search for stm32/enc28j60/tcp".

Comment: As you see , I search and can not find usefull documentation or source code

Comment: Good point. I was not clear. These three are all independent (you can have TCP running elsewhere, you can have enc28j60 connected to another microcontroller, etc.) so you'll probably have to look for something *similar* if there isn't already a project doing exactly what you want. Documentation for enc28j60 exists, same for stm32f3 chips and tcp protocol. You will also probably need to learn a bit about debugging and problem solving if you wish to do this yourself, otherwise you'll probably need to find someone to do it for you.